# To print the entire sub tree of a given tree recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures

I know how to print the left and right view of a binary tree, but I want to print the entire left subtree of a given tree recursively. So, below is the code I use, and though I am getting the desired output, I feel this is not the proper approach. Is there any other way to achieve the same result without setting the root node's right child to `nullptr`?

```
#include<iostream>   
using namespace std;

class node
{
    public:
        int data;
        node *lchild;
        node *rchild;
};

node *CreateNode(int data)
{
    node *NewNode = new node();
    NewNode->data = data;
    NewNode->lchild = nullptr;
    NewNode->rchild = nullptr;
    return NewNode;
}

void printEntireTree(node *root)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
        return;
    else
    {
        cout << root->data<<endl;
        printEntireTree(root->lchild);
        printEntireTree(root->rchild);
    }
}

int main()
{
    node *root = CreateNode(3);
    root->lchild = CreateNode(1);
    root->rchild = CreateNode(4);
    root->lchild->rchild = CreateNode(2);
    root->lchild->lchild = CreateNode(7);
    root->lchild->lchild->lchild = CreateNode(8);
    root->lchild->lchild->rchild = CreateNode(9);
    root->rchild->lchild = CreateNode(5);   
    cout << "to print entire left sub tree" << endl;
    node *temp = root->rchild;
    root->rchild = nullptr;
    printEntireTree(root);
    root->rchild = temp;
    temp = root->lchild;
    cout << "entire right sub tree is" << endl;
    root->lchild = nullptr;
    printEntireTree(root);
    root->lchild = temp;
}
```

Comment: What is not proper about it? What do you want different?

Comment: Printing trees is a very common and thoroughly documented problem. You are required to search (and debug) before asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>   
using namespace std;

class node
{
  public:
  int data;
  node *lchild;
  node *rchild;
  };

  node *CreateNode(int data)
  {
        node *NewNode = new node();
        NewNode->data = data;
        NewNode->lchild = nullptr;
          NewNode->rchild = nullptr;
          return NewNode;
  }


  void printEntireTree(node *root, node *ro2)
  {
    if(root== ro2->lchild || root== ro2->rchild)
    {
        cout << ro2->data<<endl;
    }
    
    if (root == nullptr)
        return;
    else
    {
        cout << root->data<<endl;
        printEntireTree(root->lchild, ro2);
        printEntireTree(root->rchild, ro2);
    }
  }




  int main()
  {
  node *root = CreateNode(3);
  root->lchild = CreateNode(1);
  root->rchild = CreateNode(4);
  root->lchild->rchild = CreateNode(2);
  root->lchild->lchild = CreateNode(7);
  root->lchild->lchild->lchild = CreateNode(8);
  root->lchild->lchild->rchild = CreateNode(9);
  root->rchild->lchild = CreateNode(5);   
  cout << "to print entire left sub tree" << endl;
  printEntireTree(root->lchild, root);
  cout << "entire right sub tree is" << endl;
  printEntireTree(root->rchild, root);
  }
```

Comment: Dont forget to upvote :p

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow, don't forget to explain your code with a small description ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).